# Facebook image-post like URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

When getting a like dialogue for a facebook text-only post, the like count is correct:

```
<div class="fb-like"
data-href="https://www.facebook.com/newyorkbakery/posts/955104857880192"
data-layout="button_count"
data-action="like"
></div>
```

[image: correct like count]

When attempting to do the same for a post with image, the results are inconsistent and none are correct.  These URLs in the browser give a page with 26 likes.

```
  <div class="fb-like"
  data-href="https://www.facebook.com/newyorkbakery/posts/954088621315149"
  data-layout="button_count"
  data-action="like"
  ></div>
  <div class="fb-like"
  data-href="https://www.facebook.com/newyorkbakery/photos/954088621315149"
  data-layout="button_count"
  data-action="like"
  ></div>
  <div class="fb-like"
  data-href="https://www.facebook.com/newyorkbakery/photos/a.144891402234879.26789.128157730574913/954088621315149/?type=1"
  data-layout="button_count"
  data-action="like"
  ></div>
  <div class="fb-like"
  data-href="https://www.facebook.com/128157730574913_954088621315149"
  data-layout="button_count"
  data-action="like"
  ></div>
```

[image: incorrect like counts]

Can anybody shed any insight on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the plugin to count likes on content inside Facebook. You need to use Graph API requests for that.